# When I run a file through an iterator it takes a ridiculous amount of time to process; how do I optimize it?

Tags: java, json, swing, iterator, jcombobox

I am writing a little program while I'm learning to code. What I want this specific function to do it read from a txt file a JSONArray (from a JSONObject created using json.simple) and then put the values into an Array in order to then have them displayed by a JComboBox for the user to select. The reason I want it done this way is the list of things to be stored in the txt file is very large (3000+) and is changing regularly, so it should be easier to just update the file that to update the Array itself. (Yes I know its insane to store that many things in a JComboBox; I plan to change that after the thing actually works).

So for the code, here is the JSONReader part...

```
public static void JSONArrayReader(File JSONFile, String ObjName, String[] ArrayOutput) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(JSONFile));
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray JSONArray = (JSONArray) object.get(ObjName);
    Iterator<String> iterator = JSONArray.iterator();
    int j = 0;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ArrayOutput[j] = iterator.next();
        j++;
    }
}
```

And then the actual JComboBox

```
File JSONFile = new File("C:/Users/jorda/Documents/java workspace/itemNameList.txt");
    JSONReader JSONReader = new JSONReader();
    System.out.println("made it this far");
    String[] ArrayList = new String[JSONReader.JSONArraySize(JSONFile, "items")];
    JSONReader.JSONArrayReader(JSONFile, "items", ArrayList);
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(ArrayList);
    comboBox.setBounds(10, 49, 194, 31);
    frameItemSelector.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
```

For the bit in the ComboBox code that sets the Array size that's also in the JSONReader class and it just returns the value of the size of the JSONArray, it uses almost the exact same code as the JSONArrayReader method.

It runs the way it should (as far as I know) but it just takes FOREVER to run, like a solid 10 minutes to finish just finding out the size of the file.

Comment: how big is the file? Have you profiled the code?

Comment: Does it have to be json? Instead of manipulating it manually, why not save it as an object? That way you could read it in in one call. Much faster too. Just a thought.

Comment: Put in it ArrayList without finding out the size of the file, then convert it to normal array if you need to. How long does the method you provided take, without `JSONArraySize` method? If your file is really big then 10 minutes is possible.

Comment: There are about 5000 items in the JSON file, and the reason I was storing it that way is because they API I'm accessing with the program to get information about the "items" stores all of the info in JSON files so I figured it would be easier to keep everything one file type.

Comment: And thans Shadov the ArrayList and then putting it into an Array worked perfectly.